# How does the Company Attack action work?

Tags: actions, attack, realm-management, reign

I have the Reign Enchiridion book and the rules for Company Attack aren't clear enough for me to understand without either an example or additional explanation.

My confusion comes down to how lowering a Company's Quality to zero works via Attack. I understand that every use of a Quality in a month lowers it by 1 temporarily and that succeeding at an Attack (or dynamic opposed Defend action) lowers a Quality by 1, also temporarily.

Here's what I'm unclear on:

- Losses of Might and Territory are temporary until the Quality hits zero. The attack that knocks it to zero makes the loss permanent. Does this mean that whichever side lowers the other to zero first, does so permanently while it recovers all losses next month? Or is it a loss of 1 point permanently? Or is it something else?
- Once battle is joined, you can make an Attack roll every day until one side flees or one side's Might hits zero. Does each day of Attack rolls lower your used Qualities by 1? Or is this considered part of a single month level Attack? And does this mean that in a single month, over a course of several days, a Company could wipe out another? Or is that something that has to be done across several months?

Answer (score 1):

### The Basics of Company Attack

Every month, a Company can take a number of rating-linked actions equal to its rating. (*How Often?*, Ench p.91) Attacks are Might actions, and you can make a number of Attacks equal to your Might rating, at most once per day. (This allows for adventurous positioning to give you various Might raises before the day's attack.)

Attacks (*Attack*, Ench p.96) are Might + Treasure vs. Might + Territory, and the attacker and defender's Might and Treasure/Territory are both exhausted by 1 until the next month. If the defender's Might or Territory are exhausted to 0, they cannot recover. An attacker whose Might is exhausted to 0 cannot continue the attack, but can regroup and recover their Might before the next month of Company actions.

An attacker can have four possible goals:

- **Steal Treasure.** The defender's Treasure rating drops by 1, permanently. (More or less permanently, anyway; merging through Conquest uses the Treasure rating from when the attacks started.) If the attacker had a lower Treasure rating before the attack, they productively loot enough for their Treasure to go up 1, permanently. (*General Company Rules*, Ench p.88)
- **Take Territory.** The defender's Territory rating drops by 1, permanently. (Except for merging purposes after Conquest, as before.) If the attacker had a lower Territory rating before the attack, they productively annex enough for their Territory to go up 1, permanently. (*General Company Rules*, Ench p.88)
- **Blunt Might.** Exhaust the defender's might by an additional 1 point. This is not a permanent loss. (*Attack*, Ench p.96)
- **Demonstrate Power.** The attack inflicts no additional consequences on the defender, but the attacker gains Influence or Sovereignty as a raise or increase depending on what kind of history they have with their target. (*Attack*, Ench p.96)

Once an attacker announces the goal of the attack, the defender has a choice: an opposed contest or a dynamic contest. (*Resolving Attack and Defense*, Ench pp.96-97)

- **Opposed Contest.** The defender must choose this if their Might has been exhausted. Their sets act as Gobble Dice; the attacker succeeds at their goal if they still have sets remaining.
- **Dynamic Contest.** The attacker and defender can both take multi-actions per the normal combat rules: -1 die to the pool per possible result set, results are declared before the roll is made, and can be split between attacks and Gobble Die "parries" but must contain at least one attack. Once sets have hit the table, the defender can surrender if the attacker was trying to steal treasure or demonstrate power and give the attacker those goals; otherwise, defender hits exhaust the attacker's Might, and attacker hits exhaust the defender's Might or Territory, defender's choice.

Standard Conquest rules are that you have to zero out two of a rival Company's attributes, one of which must be Territory or Sovereignty. (*Total Conquest*, Ench p. 98) So, successive Attacks can accomplish this, by taking Territory through 0 through a combination of annexing and exhausting, and either stealing all the Treasure or exhausting all the Might.